# Install Mac OS on VirtualBox for Windows using iatkos to run a ruby on rails project :/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, macos, virtualbox, webrick

I have an open source project developed using ruby (ruby on rails). I'm completely new to ruby and I just need to run this project on my local server (windows). I failed to run ruby on rails using xampp, and it turned out that I need to use Webrick Server. But I noticed that Webrick server runs on mac operating system. So I decided to run a Virtual Mac OS to run on it my ruby on rails project.

I know I'm in a mess and that's why I need your help.

I downloaded and installed VirtualBox and I'm following this guide: http://www.macbreaker.com/2013/01/iatkos-ml2-mountain-lion-virtualbox.html

Now I need to download the aitkos using bittorrent client which I also have no idea what is it. I'm lost and I've followed so many tutorials with no result :/ Please help!!

Comment: You are quite wrong. You can install everything on Windows, because they are ran under ruby. Install RVM for windows (http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/) and then follow some tutorial for installing rails

Comment: And this: http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: I'll try this, thank you very much. I've also posted a question after I failed to run ruby on rails with xampp, but I got no answer. If you please check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928876/error-while-installing-imagemagick-for-ruby-on-rails-on-windows
I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need to go for Mac OS. If you have Window System, Set up the Vagrant Dev Environment. It will provide rails platform to run ROR projects i.e Linux.

1. Install VirtualBox https://www.virtualbox.org/
2. Install Vagrant http://www.vagrantup.com/
3. Create a directory where you wanna clone rails app.
4. Clone rails-dev-box repo https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box
5. Go into rails-dev-box folder and clone your repo
6. within rails-dev-box folder, type "vagrant up"
7. once vagrant installation is done, type "vagrant ssh"
8. within the server terminal, using "rvm list", check all the available ruby versions.

So Just follow this step. We can run ROR project on this environment very easily on Window.